# Flatten shading on cylinder

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, shaders, normals

[image]

This image shows two of the same curve, one beveled into a cylinder, and one extruded into a flat plane. The material is a Diffuse mixed with glossy at .1 fac.

The top cylinder gets a strong highlight down its length and visible shadows at the glancing edges due to it's curve. The flat one's gloss is much more spread out due to it being flat.

What i want is to render shading like the flat strand, but on the cylinder. It seems this should be possible with some sort of normal changing or the like? I want the effect of the flat ribbon, but if I actually use flat ribbons then they disappear at certain angles, whereas the cylinder always has the same thickness.

If I were working directly with the mesh, then I'd scale it on the view axis till it was flat. Can something like this be done to the normals within the material?

UPDATE:
Here's a picture showing the difference better. This is just the gloss, and I bent the bottom ribbon more to emphasize the difference.
[image]
The ribbon gets full lighting on it's whole surface because it is flat. The cylinder is less lit at glancing angles. I want to get the same sort of shading on the cylinder that I have on the ribbon.
[image]
This is gloss only with Incoming plugged into the normal socket. It is flattening things out, but has also fundamentally changed how the shading is working.

Comment: How about a shadeless material? (Specify your renderer btw)

Comment: @Leander shadeless is no good. I do want shading, just a specific sort. Note that the lower curve is not shadeless, it has just ended up looking all one color because it's normals all face in the same direction.

Comment: Try plugging the *Incoming* value from an *Input* > *Geometry* node into the *Normal* input on the shaders.  I think this is what you are going for but I'm not completely sure.

Comment: @PGmath I have given that a try, but it does not produce the same effect. I don't know why, as I don't fully understand what Incoming is actually doing, and I can't find a detailed explanation either.

Comment: Can you specify a little more what you're going for?  I don't understand why you can't either 1.) use an emission shader or 2.) set roughness on Diffuse to 1.00.

Comment: I'm trying to eliminate the shading from the cylinder's curve, not from its bend. I've added a picture showing only the gloss so you can see the difference.

Comment: Oh try normalizing the *incoming* value, that should fix the weird shading.

Comment: @PGmath no luck!

Comment: Can you upload the blend with your lighting setup?

Comment: What you're asking seems impossible to me. According to your second image, you would like reflections to bend only according to the "facing" of the curve. But the cylinder itself is also curving away from the camera on its sides. So how would Blender know if the facing curvature is caused by the bezier curve or the cylinder's sides ?

Comment: @ChameleonScales yeah it would somehow need to remove the data based on the curve or something. Hmm. It probably isn't possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe you are after this shading effect:

[image]

It is possible with some vector math on normals. The goal is to change normals to be pointing towards camera, but the Incoming output from Geometry node will override all normals equally, ignoring in which direction the curve is heading. Luckily we can determine the local vector of the tube's direction:

[Can I color a curve in Cycles by the direction it's running?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43102/can-i-color-a-curve-in-cycles-by-the-direction-its-running)

The rest is a matter of 2 vector cross products to get a vector incoming to camera but also orthogonal to the curve's direction:

[image]

If you want to do this on meshes, you will have to write your own OSL shader.

Comment: Yep, that's it! One question though: How could I use a normal map with that node setup?

Comment: @Drudge technicaly with this math (check Andrew's answer): https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38298/how-to-combine-two-normal-maps. The math in more detail is here: http://blog.selfshadow.com/publications/blending-in-detail/. But the normal map details added to these vectors will be skewed towards the tube edges, that cannot be avoided. I am not sure if the result will be any good.

Comment: okay, that's working. Now I also want to get it working in a pretty strange usecase. I'm experimenting with the new Bevel Normal node (https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?436279-V-ray-got-rounded-hard-edge-shader/page7) and want to use this effect with it. However, that creates a whole new source of Normals (a modified version of the Geometry Normal output, but coming out of the Bevel node.) Any idea if I can use the two together somehow? Thanks!

Comment: @Drudge You would have to get the difference of beveled normals minus ordinary normals, and add this to these flattened normals. Not sure again how it would look, it might produce artifacts. This beveled edges functionality is years far from usable though, so I wouldn't worry about it much. The whole way that Cycles works would have to change for it to be fast enough.

Comment: I guess that gets into some funky math then. It works pretty well right now. Low on options, but speed seems fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Cycles, try increasing the roughness of your glossy shader. If you're using BI, decrease the specular hardness. (This may not be what you want, but hopefully it'll help.)

**Edit**: From your second picture, it looks like you want an [anisotropic](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/nodes/types/shaders/anisotropic.html) shader. That way, you can control the glossy roughness independently for X/Y.
(This is for Cycles; if you're using BI try [tangent shading](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/blender_render/materials/properties/shading.html).)

Answer (score 2):

This is the kind of shader you might need for it, essentially light doesnt have shades and is a single color to be sure your environment isnt affected this light is only there if the lightray shines towards the camera.
So  you can still place it in a dark scene for example, without causing some red glow or so.

[image]

the effect :
[image]

Comment: Shadeless in Cycles? Interesting.

Answer (score 0):

I think you gave yourself a really big clue.

"The top cylinder gets a strong highlight down its length and visible shadows at the glancing edges due to it's curve. The flat one's gloss is much more spread out due to it being flat."

When portraying reflective surfaces lighting is as much a factor as the material. Here's an example of what I think your node set up is with HDRi lighting.

[image]

Here's the reverse node set up with the same HDRi lighting.

[image]